# Randomly Getting com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.io.IOException: Stream closed Error

Tags: java, jersey

I'm not sure where in my code would cause the error:

```
com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.io.IOException: Stream closed.
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.bufferEntity(ClientResponse.java:583)
at moveit.PipelineMetadata.checkPipelineRunStatus(PipelineMetadata.java:1013)
```

The line of code it fails on is:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
```

In this segment on code:

```
ClientResponse response = webServiceConnect(siteLine) + "/status?rev=0").accept("application/json")
                        .get(ClientResponse.class);

        // Pipeline not found
        if (response.getStatus() == 500) {

            throw new NoPipelineFoundException("Pipeline not found : " + response.getStatus());
        }

        // Other error
        if (response.getStatus() != 200 && response.getStatus() != 500) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : " + response.getStatus());
        }

        response.bufferEntity();

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);
        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        pipelineStatus = mapper.readValue(response.getEntity(String.class), PipelineStatus.class);

        pipelineRunStatus = pipelineStatus.status;
        return pipelineRunStatus;
```

Is there something wrong with my code or could this be a timeout issue from the webserver?

Comment: Have you checked if `webServiceConnect(siteLine + "/status?rev=0")` building the URL correctly in debug mode.

Comment: @Bajal yes it is, I call this every 10 seconds and it returns JSON properly the previous calls.

Comment: It is possible that the server is throttling your requests, and not sending a proper error response back when it does that.